# Magento Theme Interface

Tags: theme, design

When reading the design guide here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

This folder structure is often mentioned:

‘app/design/frontend/my_interface/my_theme/’ AND ‘skin/design/frontend/my_interface/my_theme/’

My question is what is my_interface, is that pc, tablet and mobile and so fourth?
What different interfaces can magento detect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_interface` is just a name of your design package. Themes are groupped inside design packages. Inside that pcakage, `my_theme` is the name of the theme. You can have many themes inside a package. Default theme is always named `default` and other themes inherit from that default theme - so you can easily create any numer of sub-themes that override selected parts of the default theme.